# Best practices for typical consumer backups on a Windows PC

Tags: windows-10, backup

I was surprised to find that there wasn't already a question about this. It's well known that you should backup your data. There's lots of tools for this. Backing up data is rather non-trivial, however, because there's multiple cases to consider. What if we want to completely restore our system exactly as it was (as close as reasonably possible) from a backup? What if we want to restore just certain files.

My past experiences with various backup software has been mixed. Various errors occurring when trying to copy certain files. Backup ends up not having any easy way to restore after a critical issue (eg, hard drive fails).

I'm wondering what the best practices are for regular consumers, where they probably don't have RAID or the like and just have a single extra hard drive to backup on. What software solutions are there that work well? How should they be used?

Comment: This question is way to broad, depends too highly on specific scenarios, and will only attract opinion-based answers -- voting to close.  PS: RAID =/= Backup.

Comment: "Any data not stored in at least three distinct locations ought to be considered temporary." Something like Acronis will give you bootable, restorable backups. Something like Backblaze or CrashPlan will give you your third location.

Answer (score -1):

The free version of [VEEAM Endpoint Backup](https://www.veeam.com/de/endpoint-backup-free.html) provides full disaster recovery and should cover all end-user scenarios. It's quick and very easy to use.